# No me aparece el @decorador cuando lo imprimo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

En el siguiente código:

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

def decorador(funcion_entrada):
  def funcion_salida(niño):
    if niño in range(1, 12):
     print("Hola niño mucho gusto")
    elif niño in range(13, 18):
     print("Hola adolescente mucho gusto")
    else:
     funcion_entrada(niño)
     print("Hola joven mucho gusto")
  return funcion_salida

@decorador
def saludo(edad):
  print("Tu edad es " + edad)

saludo(14)
input()
```

el @decorador de abajo no me aparece, y solo me aparece la función de arriba, es decir no me aparece "Tu edad es " + edad, ya lo puse en str(edad), pero cuando lo pongo no me aparecen bien los códigos de arriba. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu decorador sólo invoca la función original cuando la edad es de 18 o más, debido a que la llamada está dentro del `else` que se ejecutará sólo en ese caso.

Para que la función original se invoque siempre, debe ir fuera del condicional, así:

```py
def decorador(funcion_entrada):
  def funcion_salida(niño):
    if niño in range(1, 12):
      print("Hola niño mucho gusto")
    elif niño in range(13, 18):
      print("Hola adolescente mucho gusto")
    else:
      print("Hola joven mucho gusto")
    funcion_entrada(niño)
  return funcion_salida
```

Otra cosa, la función `saludo` estaba mal, pues intentaba concatenar una cadena ("Tu edad es") con un entero, lo cual no puede hacerse. Puedes usar mejor f-strings para insertar el valor de la variable `edad` dentro de la cadena, así:

```
@decorador
def saludo(edad):
  print(f"Tu edad es {edad}")
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
saludo(14)
---
Hola adolescente mucho gusto
Tu edad es 14
```